# Saving user textarea contents into browser storage

Tags: javascript, autosave, user-data

I'd like to make an autosave feature, but without using server storage and flash. What's the preferred cross browser way to save a textarea, then recall it from browser storage? Internet explorer has userdata afaik but what about the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either [Local Storage or Session Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) (works in IE8 *and* other browsers).